# Creating a search bar for a table view that has multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array, uisearchbar

Rights now I have implemented a search bar for a table view that has multiple sections. However, when I try to a create a multidimensional array for my rows variable I get errors in my code. Here is the code I currently have without errors.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var rows: [String] = ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3"]
    var sections: [String] = ["section 1", "section 2", "section 3"]
    var search = [String]()
    var searching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return search.count
        } else {
            return rows.count
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell")
        if searching {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = rows[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell!
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        search =  rows.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

How would I create a multidimensional array for my rows variable so that there are different strings in each cell of a section while still using the search bar?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separately creating a a rows array and sections array, you can combine them together. When searching is false, show data for dataArray. When a user is searching, append results to searchArray and show that in the tableView. I would recommend watching some YouTube videos on this before pushing forward in your app. Goodluck!

```
let dataArray: [(sectionTitle: String, rowTitles: [String])] = [
    (sectionTitle: "section1", rowTitles: ["item1", "item2"]),
    (sectionTitle: "section2", rowTitles: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]),
    (sectionTitle: "section3", rowTitles: ["item1", "item3"]),
]

let searchArray = [(sectionTitle: String, rowTitles: [String])]()
```